# Vuejs 2 Using accounting.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3, accounting.js

Since the currency filter is deprecated in vue2
I need to import/ use external library accounting.js
But I'm facing problem to use accounting.js in my component.

The console show error like this:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "accounting" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
>   (found in component  at C:\project\resources\assets\js\components\ItemProductView.vue)

Here is my **app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

var accounting = require('./accounting');

module.exports = accounting;    

import BannerView from './components/BannerView.vue';
import CategoryView from './components/CategoryView.vue';
import TopProductView from './components/TopProductView.vue';    

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        message: 'hello'
    },
    components:{
        BannerView, CategoryView, TopProductView
    },

});
```

and the **TopProductView.vue** file:

```
    <template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" v-for="item in list">
            {{accounting.formatNumber(item.price)}}
            <item-product-view :item="item"></item-product-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ItemProductView from './ItemProductView.vue';

    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.fetchList();
        },
        components:{
            ItemProductView
        },
        data() {
            return {
                list: [],
            };
        },
        methods: {
            fetchList: function() {
                    this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl+'/top-product').then(function (response) {
                    this.list = response.data;
                });
            },
        }
    }

</script>
```

Please help me to find the solution...

Thanks in advance

Hendra1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer..
Create a global filter like this in app.js

```
Vue.filter('currency', function(val){
    return accounting.formatNumber(val)
})
```

and use it in the component like usual

```
item.price | currency
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass decimal points to the global filter which I find really handy.

```
Vue.filter('currency', function(val, dec){
return accounting.formatMoney(val, '$', dec)
})
```

and then use it in your component

```
{{ item.price | currency(2) }} // $1,200.00
```

If you don't pass any decimal value it will keep original number.

```
{{ item.price | currency }} // $1,200
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your **TopProductView.vue**:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" v-for="item in list">
    {{accounting.formatNumber(item.price)}}
    <item-product-view :item="item"></item-product-view>
</div>
```

You can think `accounting.formatNumber()` as `this.accounting.formatNumber()`, and the `accounting` doesn't exist in your ViewModel, neither data nor methods.

Wrap the `accounting.formatNumber` with a method in the ViewModel, or use a computed property.

Comment: Adding to that, you could make it available everywhere like this: `Vue.prototype.$accounting = accounting` (do this before starting the App). Then you can use $accounting() in any template.

Comment: Hi thank for reply, I have tried both solution but still no luck.. is there any another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import {accounting} from './accounting.js'
window.accounting = accounting

Vue.filter(currency, function(val) {
  return window.accounting.toFixed(val, 2); // or use whatever accounting function you want.
})
```